# Does proving an equal condition prove greater than or equal condition?

Tags: algorithms, solution-verification, asymptotics

Imagine I have to prove

$\sum_{i=0}^{d}a_i n^i \leq cn^k$ for $k\geq d$ and for some value $c$.

Now, let's say that someone proved that

$c_1n^k \leq \sum_{i=0}^{d}a_i n^i \leq c_2n^k$ but for $k = d$.

My question is:

Does proving the former automatically prove the latter? I kind of think **no**, because we are left to prove for $k>d$, but I could be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works if everything is positive and $n$ and $d$ are integers, as you then have $cn^k \ge cn^d$

Comment: @Henry .Thanks, that I know! But, that's what I meant **automatically**? We would need to state what you said right?